# Get First Elements From List Of Tuples

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

I have a List with this format [ (Int, [(Int, Int, Float)]) ].
Its a list of Nodes and their Edges on a graph. Each tuple of the list contains :
(Node, [(startNode, endNode, Weight)]). What id like to do is create a list of all the Nodes. I've tried to this using:

```
nodes xs = map fst xs
```

But it does not work and i have no clue why. Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
To be more specific these are the data structures i am using

```
data Graph = G [(Node, [Edge])]

data Node = N Integer

type Edge = ( Node, Node, Float )
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? Errors? Results not matching your expectations?

Comment: it wont compile, i get the following error "Couldn't match expected type `[(Node, b0)]'
                with actual type `Graph'
    In the second argument of `map', namely `xs'
    In the expression: map fst xs
    In an equation for `nodes': nodes xs = map fst xs"

Comment: @cotsy You'll have to do something like `getFsts (G xs) = map fst xs`.  You have to unwrap the list from the `G` data constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the data from the `Graph` data type to operate on it.  The easiest way would be to do something like

```
mapG :: ([(Node, [Edge])] -> a) -> Graph -> a
mapG f (G nodes) = map f nodes
```

Then you could just use it as

```
> let xs = G [(N 1, []), (N 2, [])]
> mapG fst xs
[N 1, N 2]
```

The type of `Graph` is not a list, it's a wrapper around a list.  You might instead consider just using a type alias since you aren't using any features of Haskell's data types, something more like

```
type Edge = (Node, Node, Float)
type Node = Integer
type Graph = [(Node, [Edge])]
```

Then you can easily do

```
> let xs = [(1, []), (2, [])] :: Graph
> :type xs
xs :: Graph
> map fst xs
[1, 2]
```

---

So, a quick overview of types in Haskell.  There are 4 main ways to declare something that can be used in a type signature: `type`, `newtype`, `data`, and `class`.

### `type`

The easiest to understand, anything declared as a `type` is simply an alias.  So

```
type Node = Integer
```

Is the exact same as `Integer` itself.  It can be used anywhere `Integer` is used, and vice-versa.  All this construct is for is to make your intentions more clear, such as the pre-defined `FilePath` type that is an alias for `String`.  If you see a function

```
writeToFile :: String -> String -> IO ()
```

compared to

```
writeToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

You immediately know in the second one that the first argument is the file path without having to look at anything else.  Types can also be used to make synonyms for more complex types, such as

```
type Edge = (Node, Node, Float)
```

Now you can write `Edge` everywhere you want this tuple, which is much more succinct and easy to understand.  `type`s can also be parameterized

```
type List a = [a]
```

By using `type`, you also get all the typeclass instances for what you're aliasing, so for example you can add two `Node`s together with the usual `+` and get back a `Node`.

### `newtype`

A slightly beefier version of `type`, `newtype`s have to follow a particular form.  They have a single constructor of a single type, and are usually used as an alias where you don't want people being able to really see what's inside.  For example:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
```

creates a type called `MyInt` that contains a single value of type `Int`.  This is (almost always) optimized away at compile time, so once the program runs `MyInt` takes up the same memory as `Int`, but at compile time `MyInt` and `Int` can not be used interchangeably.  These become very useful later.  Like `type`s, they can be parameterized, but unlike types you don't get instances for free.  `MyInt` does not implement `Num` by default, so you can't add them together.

### `data`

This is a very complex subject, so I'll gloss over a lot.  A `data` type is something entirely new, not just an alias.  It can have 1 or more constructors that take 0 or more arguments each.  `Bool` is a data type that has 2 constructors, each with 0 arguments:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

`Maybe` has two constructors, but one takes an argument:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

And here we see that `Maybe` is also parameterized.  These `data` types also do not implement the typeclass instances of their contents, since in general this is impossible.  You can also provide multiple parameters to `data` types such as

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

If you had a data type like

```
data Node = N Integer
```

Then `Integer` is not the same type as `Node`, and vice-versa.  In order to convert an `Integer` into a `Node`, you have to use the `N` constructor.  You can think of constructors as a special kind of function, you can even ask for their types in GHCi:

```
> :type Just
Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

### `class`

This is the most abstract one.  Typeclasses don't define a type directly, instead they provide a sort of prototype for what an instance of that typeclass would look like.  For example, the `Eq` typeclass is essentially defined as

```
class Eq a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    a /= b = not (a == b)
```

Here `Eq` says that a type that implements this class must provide a definition for the function `(==)`, and can optionally provide a definition for `(/=)`, but there is a default implementation in case you don't provide it.  `data Node` could implement this as

```
instance Eq Node where
    (N a) == (N b) = a == b
```

---

There is enough information, details, and extensions to the Haskell type system that you could fill a few books, so don't expect this to be comprehensive in any form.  There are entire topics that I didn't even mention, but this should be a good primer for you.

---

As for generating edges, that's up to you.  I don't know what your graph is being used for or what kind of data you expect to put in it, so I don't think I can really help you there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have changed to the type alias(although i am not sure why, must read up more on it) and everythings working now!Thanks again!

Comment: Hey bheklir, one more thing if you dont mind. How would i go about generating a list of the edges?